# solr strfield with haystack django

Tags: django-haystack

For one of my fields, I require solr.StrField but it doesn't seem to be supported by Haystack.  Is there a way i can create schema.xml with ./manage.py build_solr_schema with the strfield included?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about haystack, but you could always edit your existing schema.xml instead of relying on a tool to create it for you.